# Remove strings from list that start similarly - python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings. The strings are pretty long. I want to remove the strings whose first 10 characters or more are the same and keep only one of them. For example:

```
lst = ['I am going today to London', 'I am going today to Tokyo', 'My name is name']
```

Should give,

```
lst = ['I am going today to Tokyo', 'My name is name']
```

Any of the strings can be retained. How to do this efficiently?

Comment: Which one should be kept? What if the string is *less* than 10 chars long?

Comment: As I've said above, any one can be kept. It wont be less than 10 chars long. 10 was just a random number. The number could be anything. If it is more than that, just skip over it using a `try-except` @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: What have you tried, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: Some person is just downvoting everything related to this question. God knows what vengeance he has. :(

Comment: well maybe it is because your question shows NO effort on your site. SO is for helping with specific problems not for 'write my code' style of questions :) [note I didn't down vote but I voted to close bc of this]

Comment: That doesn't mean the person should downvote all answers. Anyway, I think my question is pretty specific and that's why I've received these many answers. For such a small question I don't think I should put all that I tried. Thanks for the suggestions! :) @Daij-Djan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using [**set**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) object:

```
lst = ['I am going today to London', 'I am going today to Tokyo', 'My name is name']
s10 = set()
result = []
for l in lst:
    if (l[0:10] not in s10): result.append(l)
    s10.add(l[0:10])

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['I am going today to London', 'My name is name']
```

---

`l[0:10] not in s10` - test first 10 characters of the line `l[0:10]` for non-membership **in** set `s10`(`s10` is filling with unique 10-character sequences)

Comment: The op wants the fist match (tokyo), your solution gives the second (london)

Comment: @PedroLobito: nope, first of all it is specified that *any* is sufficient, and furthermore london is the first match. Tokyo is the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pick_one_from_each_equivalence_class(original_list, equivalence_key_function):
    res = []
    equivalence_classes = set()
    for value in original_list:
        equivalence_class = equivalence_key_function(value)
        if equivalence_class not in equivalence_classes:
            res.append(value)
            equivalence_classes.add(equivalence_class)
    return res

pick_one_from_each_equivalence_class(lst, lambda x: x[:10])
```

Comment: This does what was asked. Will the downvoter care to explain what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: This is just a code dump with no explanation as to how it solves the OP's problem (it's obvious to you and me, but the OP may not know much). Also SO isn't a code writing service and it's not very useful to encourage people to treat it like one by answering questions like this. Also you had a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @jonrsharpe.
I like writing clean, self-explanatory, self-documenting code.
If something is still not clear to the OP or to anyone for some reason, they are always welcome to ask in a comment, upon which one can answer (either in a comment or by editing the answer).
If you compare my answer to the accepted one (by RomanPerekhrest) you see it is more general, more modular, and uses meaningful names. Also, unless explicitly asked for, I'd say the explanations there are totally redundant. This is production-quality code, not a "let's-hope-I'll-never-revisit-it" script.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary to get uniqueness:

```
dict((x[:10]: x) for x in lst).values()
```